# Ruby call method on object instead of passing object as argument to method

Tags: ruby, methods

Trying to understand how to write an instance method that I can call on an object (via the Object#my_method notation). I've only been able to get the desired results by passing my object as an argument to the method, but I'd like to understand an alternate way of writing methods.

```
class Anagram
  attr_reader :test_word

  def initialize(test_word)
    @test_word = test_word.downcase
  end

  def word_stats(word)
    word.downcase.split("").inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }
  end

  def match(word_list)
    word_list.delete_if { |word| word.downcase == test_word }
      word_list.find_all do |word|
        word_stats(test_word) == word_stats(word)  # <= ** THIS LINE **
      end
  end

end
```

I know I'd need to change the `word_stats` method, but I'm unsure how to rewrite that line in bold so that I could instead do something like this:

```
test_word.word_stats == word.word_stats
```

Is this an appropriate place for `send` ? Is there a way to write the `word_stats` method so that it requires no argument?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you need to define `word_stats` for class `word.class`, which I expect is `String`:

```
class String
  def word_stats
    self.downcase.split("").inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }
  end
end

"My dog has fleas".word_stats
  #=> {"m"=>1, "y"=>1, " "=>3, "d"=>1, "o"=>1, "g"=>1, 
  #    "h=>1,  "a"=>2, "s"=>2, "f"=>1, "l"=>1, "e"=>1}
```

Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: The functionality this approach provides is what I'm looking for, but I've been warned against metaprogramming in this way (i.e. 'if you're sticking your method definitions inside of a core Ruby class, you're doing it wrong' unless of course you're writing a wrapper, a library, etc.)

Comment: re: "Doing it wrong": It's perfectly OK to do that if you're not sharing that code with others, where it could overwrite or cause collisions with other code, resulting in a bug that is really difficult to track down. The idea is we *can* extend classes, but we want to do it carefully and be aware of the possible consequences.

Comment: Jim, whether you want to define a new `String` method or not, it's your only choice if you want to write `word.word_stats`, which is the same as `word.send(:word_stats)`. That will only work when the instance method `:word_class` has been defined for for class `word.class`. Incidentally, this isn't metaprogramming; it's garden-variety method creation.

Comment: Interesting. I was wondering why word.send(:word_stats) wasn't working. If I'm understanding you correctly, you saying that `word.send(:word_stats)` requires the method `word_stats` to be defined at the class level for the object I'm calling `send` on? To put it more simply, are both cases looking in the class of `word`, which is String, and finding nothing?

Comment: Yes, exactly, except it's not really "both cases", as methods are implemented with `send` (but I know what you mean). To be precise, you should say "the *instance* method `word_stat`", as class methods can be defined for the class as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your method to require an argument, then don't specify one in its definition.  In the method, if you need to refer to the whole object on which it was invoked then you can do so via the `self` keyword, but usually you need only to access its attributes, which you can do directly.

```
def word_stats
    @test_word.downcase.split("").inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }
end
```

Comment: I'm wondering how I can call the word_stats method on multiple objects. Ideally I'd like to be able to call word_stats on more than just the @test_word object. Can I do this without hardcoding the name of a specific object inside of the method definition as in your example?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with MonkeyPatching, especially if you have a small program that only does Anagram stuff. If you aren't working on a large or open source project. Monkey Patch away!

aside: Look up Ruby Refinements for a good way to limit the scope of your monkey patches in Ruby 2.0+

I would suggest changing your method to a boolean and naming it for what it does, check to see if the word is an anagram.

I've also included a slightly more obvious algorithm.

```
class String
  def anagram? ( check_me )
    self.downcase.chars.sort == check_me.downcase.chars.sort
  end
end

def match(word_list)
  word_list.delete_if { |word| word.downcase == test_word.downcase } # might want to downcase test_word as well, unless you know it's downcase already
  word_list.find_all do |word|
    word.anagram?(test_word)
  end
end
```